# Coerce some regression coefficients to certain values in R

Tags: r, lm

I am doing a simple regression using lm

```
model <- lm(response ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5)
```

I would like to **calculate all other coefficients given that** `x1 = 1` and `x2 = 0.5`.

The real model has many more coefficients and the values of some of the coefficients need to be restricted to be equal to certain values (those values are outside of my control).

Comment: `lm(I(response - x1 - 0.5*x2) ~ x3 + x4 + x5)` ?

Comment: Of course! Many thanks